# What is the best way to update d3 charts using - AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, d3.js

I've learned few blocks of `d3`. And I've made a responsive d3 histogram with the help of jquery.

Now that I wanted to go a bit forward on updating d3 charts using ajax.

I've just stepped into jquery.

And know a few bits how ajax works.

Searching for a long time but I couldn't get any working example on the official d3 site or anywhere else.

Any help will be fruitful for me to get on the basic blocks of updating d3 charts through ajax.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: No. I haven't tried anything related to ajax. But the histogram what I've built. I wanted to add a dropdown and update it through AJAX. And the link you've provided I'm only getting error as There was a error creating your contact and there's no chart visible too.

Comment: @iJay All I get is 500 internal server error alert messages...

Comment: I already navigated to that page. There's a text to type something. When I type something and hit enter i get error as I've mentioned prior comment.

Comment: @iJay - I don't find anything that is being updated through ajax.

Comment: @Anupam - I do know how AJAX works. I'm new to javascript and I'm not that good at it. I'm learning d3 and I've created a histogram by looking a example that was available through a site. Now I wanted that histogram to be updated through AJAX. And I don't have any idea on where or how to start it. Can you help me out?

Comment: @Unknown User See my answer.

Comment: @UnknownUser D3 charts expect data in JSON/csv format . All you have to do is call the d3 function in your ajax success and pass the data to it. Could you post the d3 function here ?

Comment: Sure... I'll provide the fiddle in a moment.

Comment: @Monodeep - Here's the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fJGaZ/). I've created a responsive histogram. But how will i update this through AJAX?

Comment: @UnknownUser **To see how to use AJAX to dynamically update content based on real time data, see my [Dynamic-table github project](https://github.com/anupamkumar/javascript_web_components/tree/master/dynamic_table)**

Host the project on your localserver. (Can be anything WAMP/LAMP/Tomcat whatever) and open sample.html

Now, change the content in datafile.json. You will immediately see the change in the rendered on the table. 

You want to achieve the same functionality, but with d3 charts. But the idea of how I fetch the data and process it periodically remains the same.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to call your d3 function in your ajax success:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'url to your web servise',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            data: "{}", 
            success: function (data) {
               var pos_data = data;
               div_name = "div.histogram";

        draw_histogram(div_name, pos_data);

            },
            error: function (result) {



}
    })



//The drawing of the histogram has been broken out from the data retrial 
    // or computation. (In this case the 'Irwin-Hall distribution' computation above)

    function draw_histogram(reference, pos_data){

        $(reference).empty()

        //The drawing code needs to reference a responsive elements dimneions
        var width = $(reference).width();
        // var width = $(reference).empty().width(); we can chain for effeicanecy as jquery returns jquery.

        // var height = 230;  // We don't want the height to be responsive.

        var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 30},
        // width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


        var histogram = d3.layout.histogram() (pos_data);
        //var neg_histogram = d3.layout.histogram()(neg_data);

        var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(histogram.map(function(d) { return d.x; }))
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");


        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(histogram.map(function(d) { return d.y; }))])
            .range([0, height]);

        //var ny = d3.scale.linear()
        //    .domain([0, d3.max(neg_histogram.map(function(d) { return d.y; }))])
        //    .range([0, height]);

        var svg = d3.select(reference).append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height + 20);



        svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(histogram)
          .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y); });


        svg.append("line")
            .attr("x1", 0)
            .attr("x2", width)
            .attr("y1", height)
            .attr("y2", height);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height)  + ")")
            .call(xAxis);
    };

    //Bind the window resize to the draw method.
    //A simple bind example is

    //A better idom for binding with resize is to debounce
    var debounce = function(fn, timeout) 
    {
      var timeoutID = -1;
      return function() {
        if (timeoutID > -1) {
          window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        }
        timeoutID = window.setTimeout(fn, timeout);
      }
    };

    var debounced_draw = debounce(function() {
      draw_histogram(div_name, pos_data);
    }, 125);

    $(window).resize(debounced_draw);
```

Comment: Let me give it a try and get back.

Comment: It would be less expensive on the browser if you'd check the existing Pos_data before calling the draw_histogram() again and again.

Answer (score 31):

I know the OP specified jQuery, but for those Googlers not wanting another framework, there is a native D3 way of doing this, using either [request](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#request) or [json](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#json):

```
d3.request(url, function(error, response) {
    // Now use response to do some d3 magic
});
```

or

```
d3.json(url, function(error, response) {
    // Now use response to do some d3 magic
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The idea of any AJAX request is to send request to a page that will generate a HTML markup or data that can be used by client. When you want your dropdown to update via AJAX, make sure the server sends the list of drop-down items as a XML/JSON or HTML markup and your caller function places the HTML at the appropriate place.

If you want real-time updating, consider asking the server for data periodically and then matching the data against your last copy and see if new data has arrived. If it has, re-render.

**To see how to use AJAX to dynamically update content based in real time check out my [Dynamic-table github project](https://github.com/anupamkumar/javascript_web_components/tree/master/dynamic_table)**

Host the project on your localserver. (Can be anything WAMP/LAMP/Tomcat whatever) and open sample.html

Now, change the content in datafile.json. You will immediately see the change in the rendered on the table.

You want to achieve the same functionality, but with d3 charts. But the idea of how I fetch the content and process it periodically remains the same.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what I'm looking is in the fiddle. I wanted to update that chart which created using d3 through AJAX.

Comment: Yeah, I got what you want. To achieve what you want, You should to separate the creation of chart and fetching of data for drawing the chart into two different functions. Have an function make AJAX requests to server periodically. And compare the data you get from the server with your pos_data variable. If the data is different you will call the draw_histogram() method. To see how to make periodic calls check out the dynamic_table.js::poll() method from my github link. And then do a setInterval(poll(), <number of seconds>)