# How to display children nodes in batches - d3JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, treemap

I have a tree with d3js, the nodes under the parent node (root) have upto 4 thousand children. I dont want to display 4 thousand children nodes at once when parent node is clicked. Is there anyone who has ever implemented something like a next - prev on d3js tree?

Simply put like this, out of the 4 thousand children nodes,i want 40 of them displayed first and then i have a next and prev button to appear. As soon as next is clicked, a new set of 10 nodes appear while the previous disappears. until i can navigate the whole 4 thousand.

Or another way is to have something like pagination for the nodes of 4 thousand children nodes so that one can navigate through them easity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use AJAX to load new sets of data.

Without seeing any of your code or the specific use of the data being displayed I couldn't tell you exactly what you'd want to do though. But you'd either want to auto increment/decrement programmatically by a value of 10, or you can send parameters to your AJAX request function to call specific data sets.

Here is a thread about using AJAX with D3 charts

[What is the best way to update d3 charts using - AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784164/what-is-the-best-way-to-update-d3-charts-using-ajax)

Comment: OK thanks for your response, that is more generic. can i have a little code snippet that just shows how i can have few nodes displayed at first and have others shown on click of a button? thanks